# Perdendo Session Codeigniter

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, codeigniter, aplicação-web

Boa tarde pessoal, comecei um estagio e me passaram um ecommerce pra mexer, ele tem CodeIgniter(eu nunca tinha mexido)e um biblioteca chamada ion auth(pra login) porém quando faço o login ele define a session corretamente, ao ir para o painel de usuário onde preciso da session pra identificar o usuário a session aparece como NULL, alguém pode me dar uma luz?

```
if ($password === TRUE)
{
    if ($user->active == 0)
    {
        $this->trigger_events('post_login_unsuccessful');
        $this->set_error('login_unsuccessful_not_active');

        return FALSE;
    }
  //  echo '<pre>';print_r($user);echo'</pre>';
    $this->set_session($user);
    $this->update_last_login($user->id);
    $this->clear_login_attempts($identity);

    if ($remember && $this->config->item('remember_users', 'ion_auth'))
    {
        $this->remember_user($user->id);
    }

    $this->trigger_events(array('post_login', 'post_login_successful'));
    $this->set_message('login_successful');

    return TRUE;
}
```

Quando entra nesse codigo no controller aparece a `$_SESSION['user_id']` como `NULL`.

```
$idUser = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$qtdPedidos  = count($this->produtoscliente_model->getQtdPedidosCliente($idUser));
$qtdProdutos = $this->produtoscliente_model->getQtdProdutosCliente($idUser);
```

Comment: CodeIgniter possui uma biblioteca própria para session, use-a. Ela mesma faz a inicialização da sessão. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: já tentei com ela tbm, mas sempre que troca de pagina a session perde.

Comment: Uma vez eu tive um problema similar, foi algo no servidor e resolveu reiniciando (o que é uma pena não saber o que aconteceu). A diferença que eu não estava usando nenhum framework.

Comment: consegui revolver adicionando session_start(); no index e comentando as partes onde eram chamada session no próprio framework

Comment: Eu tive esse problema no meu trabalho também e era incompatibilidade com as versões do PHP.